# Set Canvas origin to lower-left corner in Skia

Tags: c#, skiasharp, skia

How can I change the origin of a Canvas to the lower-left corner instead of the default top-left corner?

```
void draw(SkCanvas* canvas) {
  SkPaint p;
  p.setColor(SK_ColorRED);
  p.setAntiAlias(true);
  p.setStyle(SkPaint::kStroke_Style);
  p.setStrokeWidth(10);

  canvas->drawLine(200, 20, 100, 100, p);
}
```

https://fiddle.skia.org/c/e5fe08a701838b078c0ec6c98ef052c8

Comment: Is this really C# code (as it is tagged as `c#`)? Looks more like C or C++ to me.

Comment: Use Scale(1, -1) to invert the Y-axis, Translate(0, height) to move the origin.

Comment: Do not use canvas->scale(1, -1); that will flip text upside down. To invert the y-axis in skia, I was not able to find a better method than manually adding a negative sign to every y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not believe you can change the origin, You can use the bounds of the canvas to get the desired points.

```
void draw(SkCanvas* canvas) {
    SkPaint p;
    p.setColor(SK_ColorRED);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStyle(SkPaint::kStroke_Style);
    p.setStrokeWidth(10);
    SkRect bounds = canvas->getLocalClipBounds();
    canvas->drawLine(bounds.fLeft + 200, bounds.fBottom - 20, bounds.fLeft + 100, bounds.fBottom - 100, p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the height and width from canvas, then subtracting from it, we can get the drawing looks like origin changed to lower left corner.

Try this code

```
void draw(SkCanvas* canvas) {
    SkPaint p;

    p.setColor(SK_ColorRED);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStyle(SkPaint::kStroke_Style);
    p.setStrokeWidth(10);

    canvas->drawLine(200, canvas->getDeviceClipBounds().height()-20, 100, canvas->getDeviceClipBounds().height()-100, p);
}
```